# Python add moving average to data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, moving-average

I have a fairly large data frame in python and I am trying to add a new column for moving average.  I can add the moving average for the table as a whole, the problem is I need to do multiple moving averages based off of the values in column b.  For example:

```
Column B          Column C
1                 4
2                 5
3                 6 
1                 7
2                 8 
3                 9
```

so the new column would have the moving averages for 1,2,3,....

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. You want an average for only part of the rows, and which part is based on column B. So for instance you want the average for all rows that are a 1 in column B?

Comment: I also find your question confusing. Posting the desired output given your sample dataframe might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
MA_WINDOW = 2
data = ('C:\\Users\\Benjamin\\Desktop\\XSO.csv') 
df = pd.read_csv(data, names=['Indicie', 'Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low','Close', 'Vol', 'MA'])
df['MA'] = df.Close.rolling(window=MA_WINDOW).mean()
print(df)
```

Comment: Notes:
The CSV file contains values for 'Indicie', 'Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low','Close', 'Vol'.  The fourth line of code performs the calculation of the Moving Average.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).